# Systemd forking on different user and Restart on-failure of forked process

Tags: systemd

I have following on my unit file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Solr as a Service


[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/opt/solr/solr start
ExecStop=/opt/solr/solr stop
```

My `/opt/solr/solr` has `RUNAS solr-user` so clearly the forked process started by `solr-user`

I need to restart the systemd process when forked process went down. So I added following to unit file

```
Restart=on-failure
PIDFile=/opt/solr/solr-8080.pid
```

When I start the service as root `sudo systemctl start solr-service` the process started successfully and I get the following error and it is getting stopped and started again and again.

```
systemd[1]: New main PID 12345 does not exist or is a zombie.
```

Comment: I've never tried to let a service change its own user.  That should normally be handled by systemd which ensures users have a fresh session instead of an inherited one.  What _I_ would probably do is convert `/opt/solr/solr` to a service file, set `User=` and get rid of `Type=forking`.

Comment: If I do that I'm getting PAM errors. pam_unix(su-l:auth): auth could not identify password for solr-user I don't have enough permission to change sudoers file or any other PAM config unfortunately.